# The Wireshark is not able to collect entire data(especially TCP&UDP) of other user's packets

Tags: networking, wireshark, raw-sockets

Recently i was writing a packet-sniffer code in c but the packet sniffer showed only those packets which were directed to PC ip and only showed some packets of IGMP protocol of other users.Based on recommendation from some person i tested out with wireshark and the results are exactly the same.Is there anything i'm missing out on the functionality of wireshark or is there a flaw in my NIC?

Comment: On wireshark, did you capture packet in promiscuous mode?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yup I have captured packet in promiscuous mode and I have seperately also set to promiscuous mode using ifconfig.

Comment: What traffic do you expect to see? Usually, if connected to a switch or router you will get your packets + broadcasts.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I intend to see TCP and UDP packets which are destined to other computers in the network. But I see only packets which are destined to my PC and broadcast packets

Comment: You should be connected to a hub then. [Here's](https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-does-Wireshark-capture-network-packets-if-the-packets-are-not-directed-to-the-IP-MAC-address-of-the-machine-running-the-program/answer/Darci-Saucedo) a short explanation.